Can HTML code added in App inventor without the webviewer?
I was trying to do a sample project for my son using app inventor and its a weather predictor but i dont know how to add the HTML code without the web viewer
How can i add it in App inventor without webviewer?

HTML code:
<html>
<body>
<script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                if (window.__TOMORROW__) {
                    window.__TOMORROW__.renderWidget();
                }
                return;
            }
            const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            const js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://www.tomorrow.io/v1/widget/sdk/sdk.bundle.min.js";

            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        })(document, 'script', 'tomorrow-sdk');
        </script>

        <div class="tomorrow"
           data-location-id="132169"
           data-language="EN"
           data-unit-system="METRIC"
           data-skin="light"
           data-widget-type="upcoming"
           style="padding-bottom:22px;position:relative;"
        >
          <a
            href="https://www.tomorrow.io/weather-api/"
            rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
            style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; transform: translateX(-50%); left: 50%;"
          >
            <img
              alt="Powered by the Tomorrow.io Weather API"
              src="https://weather-website-client.tomorrow.io/img/powered-by.svg"
              width="250"
              height="18"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>


Why can't you use the web viewer?

If you just want to run a javascript, you must still use the webviewer, but it does not need to be visible. Use the Run Javascript block, and the webviewstring to return the output to your app. Alternatively, you may be able to use the website's api directly with the Web component.

Hey @Jacob It returns invalid File if i tried to execute it in my Phone.

Hey @MetricRat, Can you give more direction I couldn't understand you.

You cannot do what you are trying to do without the web viewer,
but that's not the root of your problem.
The real issue is that the URL file://C:/Users/.../Imagenpredit.html
only exists on your computer, and therefore cannot be accessed
from a phone.
The solution to this problem is to store the file online. That way, it can be accessed from any device with an internet connection.
There are many easy and free ways to store an HTML file, a good one for your case would be to use Netlify Drop. Upload the HTML file you're using, then use the link it gives to you as the URL for WebViewer.GoToUrl.

Or store the html file as an asset, and access it with http://localhost/yourhtmlfile.html

Is “store as an asset” App Engine specific? I have never used App Engine, but the problem was totally separate, this is an XY problem. You could store it in localhost but OP seemed to need it from arbitrary devices

@MetricRat It didn't work it showed refused to connect error :(

It works great but it's annoying that its a temp. link

Oh sorry, didn't realize Netlify Drop only gave temporary links. You could use GitHub pages instead. It's a little bit more complicated to set up but you should be able to get it running pretty quick if you follow the instructions at that link.

With AppInventor, you have a media folder where you can upload "assets" as a part of the aia project. These assets are built with the apk. One can store "static" html files in the media folder (for example yourhtmlfile.html) and these are accessed, for a webviewer component, with the url I showed above http://localhost/yourhtmlfile.html

Tnx for the help @Jacob

Tnx for trying to help @MetricRat
